# Android - ¿Utilizar una base de datos?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para **Android**, lo que hace mi aplicación solo es mostrar unos `ListViews` con información (Aproximadamente 100 items). Esta información siempre sera la misma y nunca cambiará. Lo que quiero saber es: **¿Cual es la mejor manera de almacenar esta información?** ¿Tenerlo todo en una base de datos? o ¿*Tipear* toda esta información en código **`Java`**?
En el caso de la primera opción, ¿Cómo configuro **`SQLite`** para que la aplicación se instale con la información ya cargada?

Comment: que clase de formato tienen tus items? id, valores distintos? o es un texto plano que listas?

Comment: **Nunca** pongas registros directamente en código. La palabra "siempre" puede cambiar en cualquier momento y necesitar modificar un registro, eliminarlo o incluso crear registros nuevos. Utilizar una base de datos te dará una mayor flexibilidad y dejará tu código muchísimo más limpio que insertando en código 100 registros.

Comment: @sioesi son objetos con un codigo y texto.

Comment: @Error404 Claro, siempre tuve la idea de la base de datos, ahora, mi pregunta seria como hacer para que los registros se encuentren en la base de datos al instalar la aplicacion?

Comment: http://www.javahispano.org/android/2011/12/27/manejo-de-datos-en-android-sqlite.html

Comment: dependiendo el caso podrias considerar guardarlo en un json o xml en los resources y ahorrarte la implementacion de la base de datos.

Comment: Puedes usar _SQLite_, que viene en el dispositivo o utilizar una _NoSQL_, como _Realm_, que también está para _Android_, y es más rapida que _SQLite_. Por último, también tienes la base de datos no relacional de _Firebase_, que ahora viene incluida en la última versión de _Android Studio_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar un archivo JSON y guardarlo en los resources de tu app, de esta manera será mucho mas fácil implementar la solución y de modificar la lista en caso de que lo requieras.
Para consumir el JSON te recomiendo utilizar [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) el cual te permite convertir objetos de java en su representación Json y viceversa de forma casi automatica.

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo que uses una base de datos SQlite en la que al instalar la app directamente haga los inserts que desees con los datos que deses y después trabajes con esta.

Aquí te dejo una guía para hacer la base de datos SQLite y todo lo que conlleva: [Guía](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2016/01/base-de-datos-sqlite-en-android-con-multiples-tablas/)

También te recomiendo que utilices el RecyclerView en vez del ListView, es un poco más dificil de implementar pero hay miles de tutoriales por internet y tampoco es mucho mas difícil de hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes almacenar algunos valores para tu app usando el SharedPreferences de android, ejemplo:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor_pref;

...
//INiciar el preferences
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //Necesita un Context

//Iniciar el editor (solo para almacenar)
editor_pref = preferences.edit();

//Guardar data
editor_pref.putString("tu_key", "tu valor");
editor_pref.putInt("tu_otra_key", 100);
...
//Salvar los cambios
editor_pref.commit();

//Recuperar data
preferences.getString("tu_key", "Puedes enviar un valor por defecto");
preferences.getInt("tu_otra_key", 0);
```

Por ejemplo, para saber si debo quitar algunos assets en mi app uso esto:

```
if (preferences.getBoolean("remove_assets", true)) {
   removeAssets();
}
```

Es una forma sencilla de almacenar algunos datos, sobre todo para controlar el comportamiento de la app!

te dejo la doc oficial: [Documentacion Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es-419)